# How to fix, ubuntu not getting ip address on hyper-v?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, hyper-v, ipv4

I am using hyper-v as a hypervisor and installed ubuntu 21 on it.

[image: os version]

There, whenever I start the VM, the eth0 (only one network interface connected,Default Switch of Hyper-v) is not getting IP and showing as down.

[image: ip down]

Please bare with my snaps, as I can't ssh to the machine to copy the output and paste here as text.

There is no /etc/network/interfaces file on my machine, as many forum questions modifying content on this file.

To make this network adapter up, I ran below command.

```
sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

Then, the network adapter is up now but without ip4 address.

[image: up but only ipv6]

To get ip address, I ran below command and it gets ip.

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

Then, I get IPv4 address.

[image: ipv4 address received]

I need to do this every time I on the machine.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu now uses `netplan` for network config. There's an article that looks helpful here: https://linuxconfig.org/netplan-network-configuration-tutorial-for-beginners

But a relevant snippet that might need to go in `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` or similar:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
```

...then run `sudo netplan apply`.

Additional info here: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_21.04&p=dhcp&f=2

Comment: There is a file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml. I edited that, and it seems there are other entries in it(enp0s3,enp0s4) but not eth0, so I added one more similar entry for eth0 and as you shared and it is working. Thank you very much for your answer.